# Putty Search - String followed by one but not two symbols

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am searching for a string in a path /home/folder/ that contains multiple .txt and .xls files. There exist instances where variable xyz is defined. An example would be:
"xyz    = if...else..."

There also exist instances where variable xyz is used as a condition. An example would be:
".... xyz==1 ..."

I want to find all instances where xyz is defined, not where xyz is used as a condition. I tried the following code and nothing worked...

```
grep --include=\*.{txt,xls} -rnw '/home/folder/' -e 'xyz\s*\=(?!=)'
grep --include=\*.{txt,xls} -rnw '/home/folder/' -e 'xyz\s*\=(?!\=)'
grep --include=\*.{txt,xls} -rnw '/home/folder/' -e 'xyz\s*\=[^=]'
```

I think my syntax is correct, but no results are returned. I tried using different shells but it made no difference. How would I search for a string in this case?

EDIT: I know instances of "xyz = ifelse" are present in files in the directory. These come up when I search using the following command:

```
grep --include=\*.{txt,xls} -rnw '/home/folder/' -e 'xyz\s*\='
```

Comment: I think you need `-P` switch to use look-arounds.

Comment: Getting to see some test data would really help, but I think the `-w` may be biting you; to me it makes no sense to specify **whole word** and then have spaces in the regex.

Comment: also, `(?!' matches those actual characters in the output. I think you need PCRE support to use them as lookahead assertions

Answer (score 1):

Both hints by *Mark* and *tink* are correct: You'll need to add the `-P` option and get rid of `-w`, using `\b` instead:

```
$ cat test.txt 
xyz = 14
xyz == 15
xyz=1
xyz==2
xyzz=4
zxyz=5

# No PCRE, no (correct) result
$ grep -e "xyz\s*\=(?!=)" test.txt 

# Missing instances without space between operator and value here
$ grep -P -w -e "xyz\s*\=(?!=)" test.txt 
xyz = 14

# Not checking for word boundary returns false positives
$ grep -P -e "xyz\s*\=(?!=)" test.txt 
xyz = 14
xyz=1
zxyz=5

# This is the result you want to see
$ grep -P -e "\bxyz\s*\=(?!=)" test.txt 
xyz = 14
xyz=1

# The same without PCRE
$ grep -e "\<xyz\s*\=[^=]" test.txt
xyz = 14
xyz=1
```

Comment: I got
    $ grep -e "\<xyz\s*\=[^=]" test.txt
to work, but not the preceding one with the -P. Can I not do -rnP? I have multiple files, and I want to know the location of matching instances. Also, if I were to look for 'xyz' instances where it is not preceded by an open parenthesis, I tried [^(]\<xyz\s*\=[^=] but it did not work

Comment: "but not the preceding one with the -P" - Hard to say what's wrong without more details, and comments are hardly the right place for that. Put it in your question if you think you need more help with that.

Comment: "Can I not do -rnP?" - Of course you can, but it won't change the matches. Did you try?

Comment: "Also, if I were to look for 'xyz' instances where it is not preceded by an open parenthesis" - As before, that's an expansion to your original question. But one hint: Word boundary.

Comment: And furthermore, now would be a good time to take the [tour] and read [ask] and the related articles to learn how to improve your questions.